# How to determine what program is doing when it becomes non responsive?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

My program is becoming non responsive when it is executing a certain function. How can I see what it's doing in real time to know why it's becoming non responsive?

It's not crashing, so I can't see the reason unfortunately. How can I find out what it's doing?

What can I do? What programs are out there that are good in this type of situation for both with and without the actual source code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run in the debugger, then break execution when the slowdown occurs.  The place it stops, more than likely, will be where your problem is.  If you start and stop multiple times, the place execution breaks most often will probably say for sure.

Or use a profiler.  Either program will work with out without source, though it is much, MUCH, easier to use them with source and debug symbols (without requires quite a bit of assembler knowledge skill on the platform you are running.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Process Monitor from Sysinternals http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Answer (score 0):

**A. with the source code**

You can attach Visual Studio to a process and press break. Afterwards have a look at the call stack. If ti is not crashing its potentially no recursion. So you should see what it is doing.

If it is a multithreaded application switch between the threads and watch the call stack.

**B. without the source code**
I assume this is hard. The only thing that can be found is external analysis. Like wireshark to watch Network activities or Process Monitor from Sysinternals (procmon.exe) to see registry or file access.